# FileNotFoundException occurs only when running outside the debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have this simple code that opens a txt file:

> StreamReader sourceFile = File.OpenText(fileName)

the thing is, when I press ctrl-f5 to start the program, I get a file doesn't exist error.
but when I press f11 to go step by step, everything runs smooth and no errors or what so ever happens and i get the desired results.
any idea what could be the cause of this?

I'm using visual studio C# express 2010.

The code in Program.cs:

> Class1.ReadPointsFile(@"Points.txt");

The function:

```
public void ReadPointsFile(string fileName)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File doesn't exist.");
                return;
            }
            using (StreamReader sourceFile = File.OpenText(fileName))
            {
                string inputLine;
                int arraySize;
                arraySize = Convert.ToInt32(sourceFile.ReadLine());
                pointsArray = new Point2D[arraySize];
                int i_keepTrack = 0;
                inputLine = sourceFile.ReadLine();
                do
                {
                    string[] Coordinations = inputLine.Split(' ');
                    pointsArray[i_keepTrack] = new Point2D(double.Parse(Coordinations[0]), double.Parse(Coordinations[1]));
                    i_keepTrack++;
                    inputLine = sourceFile.ReadLine();
                } while (inputLine != null);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You're not creating the file in an earlier line, are you?

Comment: Is the path relative or absolute?

Comment: the txt file is located in the project directory/bin/debug
@Josh i did not create any file in this project, i just read from files.

Comment: In your project properties, Debug tab, do you have a "Working Directory" specified?

Comment: @Adam it is specified as filename.txt.
I have edited the post, now the code is included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a problem of running path: debugging, you start your program on bin\debug folder (where the file is present), meanwhile using ctrl+F5 to run without debug, program starts on bin\release folder.

Comment: Thank you, this has solved it:)

Comment: No, you would at least have to switch the Build config to Release. Just hitting Ctrl+F5 doesn't change the target folder.